# Would such a natural transformation exist?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

So, I know the following definition of a Natural Transformation:

Let $F,G: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ be two functors. A natural transformation $\eta: F \implies G$ consists of morphisms $\eta_{x} \in \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{D}}(F(x), G(x))$ for every $x \in \text{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ such that for every morphism $f: x \to y; y\in\mathcal{C}$ such that the diagram:

[image]

commutes.

Now, I wanted to know what happens when $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{D}}(F(x), G(x)) = \emptyset$ for some $x$. If this happens for some $x$ would there exist some $\eta$ between $F$ and $G$ assuming that all $\eta_{x}$'s for $x$'s such that $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{D}}(F(x), G(x)) \neq \emptyset$ follow the required criteria.

In other words, I wanted to know if $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{D}}(F(x), G(x)) = \emptyset$ for some $x$ (which would mean $\eta_{x}$ for such $x$ would not exist) then it does not mean that the natural transformation $\eta$ could not exist, right??

Comment: When you say $\phi$, do you mean the empty set $\varnothing$? That's not the Greek letter phi, that's the Norwegian letter ø. And its MathJax command is `\varnothing` (or `\emptyset` for $\emptyset$).

Comment: Thanks. I mean the empty set. I will correct in a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is right, if $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{D}(F(x), G(x)) = \emptyset$ then there cannot be a natural transformation $\eta: F \Rightarrow G$ because that would require $\eta_x \in \operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{D}(F(x), G(x))$.

We could define a notion of *partial natural transformation*, much like you suggest: we only require that $\eta_x$ exists for some of the $x \in \mathcal{C}$ and we only require the relevant square to commute where it exists. It is not unthinkable that in some setting such a definition would be useful. However, I have never seen a definition like that, so I do not know if it is useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)